# Finding the power series for an integral

Tags: power-series

**Exercise** Find a power series for the function

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t^2}{1-t^4} \, dt$$

So basically what we want is to find $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$ so that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n = f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t^2}{1-t^4} \, dt$$

I'm not exactly sure where to start or what to do. Can anyone provide suggestions/advice on how to get this started? Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT: Check the proof of the taylor series.

Comment: You could just find the closed form elementary anti derivative and find solutions from there. Also remember the [“best friend” geometric series](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux7vl6zXxj0)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t^2}{1-t^4} \, dt$$ Now, using the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$f'(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x^4}=\frac{x^2}{\left(x^2-1\right) \left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{1}{2 \left(x^2+1\right)}-\frac{1}{4 (x+1)}+\frac{1}{4 (x-1)}$$ Write the series of each piece around $x=0$, recombine them and integrate termwise.